# python chatclean and email clean

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, chat, data-cleaning

I have some data from customer chatbox and I want to do some clean, and I do not know how to do it. 
what if I already have

```
def chatClean(t, Agent = True)
.......#some function in it 
def emailClean(e)
....
```

Anyone know how to apply to my main function which what I have is

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('C:/CC Data.xlsx')
a = df['TEXT'].str.lower()
```

I want to make a cleanup for 'TEXT' column and how can I apply it to get the output as csv file

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by 'clean up'.

Comment: I have function 'clean up' and I want to apply it to my main function, however, the result gives my <generator object chatClean at 0x0B456E40> instead of the original text after clean up

Comment: Please provide your clean up function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function `clean` that takes a string and returns a 'cleaned up' string, you can apply it to a column like so:

```
 df['TEXT'] = df['TEXT'].apply(clean)
```

Comment: 0       <generator object chatClean at 0x0B456E40>
1       <generator object chatClean at 0x0B4560F0>
2       <generator object chatClean at 0x0B456E10> This is what I get after I did that. So how can I get the original text after clean up